# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest not setting remote image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking's `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` to asynchronously load an online image onto a `UIImageView`.

The remote image loads very well when I use `setImageWithURLRequest:`, but when I try using `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure` the remote image is downloaded but the UIImageView does not set it as its UIImage.

Here's my code:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [_imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/fVhhR.png"]]
                       placeholderImage:nil
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , UIImage *image ){
                                    NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %d", [response statusCode]);
                                }
                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                    NSLog(@"failed loading: %@", error);
                                }
     ];
}
```

Image always loads successfully, the status code is always `200`. But I have to add `[_imageView setImage:image];` to the `success` block for the `UIImageView` to set the image.

I'm using iOS 6.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you supply a success block then you are responsible for setting the image property of your UIImageView. If you supply a nil success block then AFNetworking does it for you.

This is the relevant section of `UIImageView+AFNetworking.m` (line 117):

```
if (success) {
    success(operation.request, operation.response, responseObject);
} else {
    self.image = responseObject;
}
```

Alternatively, just use the `-setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` without the completion blocks.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I thought I could add to this: This change was made recently for 1.0.1 so that the developer could specify a transition if desired, or do some sort of processing. This is documented in CHANGES, and is now on the website documentation as well. The change was made here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/81f33ae97197b181b86d3570c3c8967bd0da028e

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after being frustrated with the docs for the library I found what Robin mentioned above. So now I'm using:

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:nil success:nil failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to retrieve image");
}];
```

Works like a charm. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The doc is very clear:

> If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block
>   to set the image of the image view before returning. If no success
>   block is specified, the default behavior of setting the image with
>   `self.image = image` is applied.

So you can either pass a nil block for success (as mentioned above) or call setImage:image yourself if you specify a block

Answer (score 1):

In your success block, you need to give the `UIImaage *image` to your `UIImageView`. I assuming you are getting the `NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %d", [response statusCode]);`

Also, it appears your placeholder image is `nil`. Don't you want a placeholder like a loading image in there?

Comment: AFNetworking's [documentation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:) for `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` states that "If the image is cached locally, the image is set immediately, otherwise the specified placeholder image will be set immediately, and then the remote image will be set once the request is finished." In my case it's not cached locally so it should be set immediately, and it's not. 

I did set the placeholder image to nil, but that shouldn't matter...

Comment: See my answer below - the documentation is unclear. Look at the source code.

Comment: The documentation is not so much "unclear" as "outdated." The behavior changed, the documentation hadn't been re-uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

For those who has stumbled upon this issue and got here while browsing and searching on the web, here's an another reason - the image might have wrong file extension. For example, the image might be saved as jpg, but someone has decided to change its file extension to png.

Here's how to check that: first you need to use your network monitoring tool (for example Charlie) and check image request "Content-Type" HTTP header. Suppose, it has value "image/png". This means the image on the backend has png file extension. Now, run your app on simulator, then go to simulator folder of your app:

/Users/you/Library/Application Support/iPhone simulator/select-folder-with-your-iOS-version/Applications/YourApp/Library/Caches/yourAppBundleId/fsCachedData/

Find your image file and add png or jpg extension to this file (AFNetworking caches image files without file extension, so need to add it in order to open it with Preview). Open it with Preview and press Tools/Show Inspector. Check for "Document Type" in the opened panel. If it's different than "PNG image" (for example JPEG image) then that's the cause and you need to fix the image itself on the backend - open it with appropriate image editing program and save it as PNG.